# How do I stop js2-mode from over-indenting?

Tags: javascript, emacs

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and I've come up empty.  It seems like `js2-mode` is really aggressive about indenting chained calls and a few other types of things, and I can't figure out how to turn it off.

A really simple example looks like this:

`emacs` does this:

```
let a = foo()
    .bar();
```

or this, in some scenarios:

```
let a = thing.foo()
             .bar();
```

When what I want is this:

```
let a = foo()
  .bar();
```

I've got `js2-basic-offset` set to `2`, and `js-chain-indent` set to `nil`.  Is there something else I need to customize?